# How to manage spec / user stories in Agile/Scrum

Tags: scrum, agile, user-stories

One of the common problems with traditional spec is that it's usually out of date. However, if we use a list of user stories as the spec, the thing is that the requirement may be scattered and cannot follow once it becomes complex.

For example, we delivered a user story and some time later, we decide to change some behaviors which make some acceptance criteria of that user story obsolete.

- If we don't update that user story and just create new one, long time later the new member cannot follow the changes. While doing regression test, our QC may miss those old changes. How can we prevent this?
- If we update the user story, then how to version those changes throughout the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, agile values working software over comprehensive documents.

If your application's behavior changes, the most important outcome associated with it is that it should work as expected.

Second comes the documentation.

Here is where you would want to think what is your preference for documentation?

1. Do you prefer to keep your user stories updated and/or grouped together?

If so you could create the new story and relate it to the old story with original descriptions. You could write the story and make the "new" acceptance criteria clearer to avoid any confusion.

2. Or do you prefer to use your regression test suite (if you have one) as the key documentation?

If so, reflect the changes there with clarity.

Or prefer your source control logs/release logs/code comments as the key source?

Then have strict commit regime, release documentations, and so on.

Now for post-live reference:

Most of the development projects I've involved, use Jira actively while development is active. Once the project moves to BAU mode, Jira is not the tool that is used often, it could  be wiki write up or support manual. Best to stick with what your company adheres to for post-live references.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that the working software is more value over the comprehensive documents. But in my case, the product is staying long enough so the team forgot the reason behind the old changes, and the logic is complex enough to understand without some kind of document.

Comment: For the option 2, I'm not sure I have enough test suite since we also do exploration test. 

For the release logs / source control, the history is so long. Do you have any example or links that related to this?

The other options are fine and I'm thinking more about them. We use Jira internally. I'm thinking about creating new story with the relationship like "replaced by"/"replaces".

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that we use Acceptance Criteria as the source of the test cases.

Comment: In a long running project, you will need to have a decent level of documentation. Especially when features  are complex and change happens often. In one of my projects, we had a nice release notes, a section in wiki which has all the releases listed in order they happened.A page corresponds to each release, where we add the release candidate details, list of  business features, deployment details, and all the useful info regarding that release. In some cases we link to jira tickets if additional data is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an internal wiki link, not able to share with you. But I think you got the idea?

Comment: What we are doing now is combining the list of user stories for a release notes. Writing release notes like Jira release notes can be costly and we will only think about that when we have a public product like Jira.

Comment: Right now, the most possible thing we can give a try is the option 1, group user stories together and relates any changes to the original user story. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The User Stories aren't a spec. They're a place holder for a future conversation. Separate the Tests/Spec from the User Story.

In many teams that TDD, you'll hear

> "The spec is the test and the test is the spec."

We keep track of the specification as close to our code as possible. So close, in fact, that it's executable code itself. This way, when a new user story comes up that contradicts the original spec, the spec (tests) *have to be* updated. The spec never gets out of sync with the code.

I hear you though.

> But you can't unit test ***everything***! Some things still have to be manually tested!

And you're right, but that doesn't mean that we can't still keep the tests separate from the story. Any QA worth their salt has a bunch of test scripts that they follow when manually testing a system. If the spec has changed, then the QA needs to update their test procedure anyway. So, just like our automated tests, these test scripts are where we keep the system specification.

Comment: We have strict schedule with less people so I don't think that I have enough test case written down. We do pairing between QC/BA and dev to make sure every body understand the requirement clearly.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that we use Acceptance Criteria as the source of the test cases.

Comment: Yes, Acceptance Criteria is the source, but shouldn't be the record, in my opinion. "We have strict schedule so I don't think that I have enough test cases written down". You're telling me you have time to do it 2 or 3 times, but not enough time to do it right the first time??

Comment: If I work on my own, it's ok. But in a team, people usually defers document things in order to complete the "working software" first. That creates a debt, and this debt is bigger after a while. That's why I'm looking for Agile testing, find a way to reduce the debt while still avoid regression bugs.

Comment: That's precisely why I recommend putting your documents in a place where they have to stay in sync with your code. Agile teams document. It keeps us nimble. Maybe we just don't create the kinds of documents that traditional PMs expect.

Comment: @ltvan: If the tests don't pass, then you don't have working software. The only way that the tests can get out of sync with the actual requirements is if the tests don't get re-executed for every (externally delivered) release. But then you also don't have a proof that your software fulfils the requirements.

Comment: "If the tests don't pass, then you don't have working software." I love it. Will be stealing that @BartvanIngenSchenau.

Comment: First, I'm talking about regression bug. Second, life is not perfect. People tend to skip rule once they got burnt for the deadline. In some area, it's easier to be discovered, but in some other area, it may take months to find out the fault. What am I supposed to do if the test get out of sync? Purnish the team? How can I re-sync the test? Tracing from stories to stories? What's the most reliable source of reference?

Comment: I personally think that the user story could be the most reliable source because that's the place where the whole team pays attention to. The risk of wrong user story is very least, while the test spec is only seen by somebody of the team: the owner and the reviewer. The reviewer might be too busy to spot out every mistakes in the test spec.

Comment: And that is why we write executable specifications @ltvan. There are two hidden assumptions to agile software development. 1. You have good code. 2. You have an automated test suite.

Comment: Not every kind of project can be automated tested. Mine can't, at least right now. Until we can apply it, I must have something reliable first. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ltvan I know we're way off topic, but take a word of advice from a guy who's been in the trenches. Every project can be tested and thinking you'll get something reliable, *then* go back to add the tests is, honestly, insane. You'll reach a reliable product much faster if the tests are there to begin with. Good luck mate. Something tells me you're going to need it.